# gem react-rails fails to install react on rails 6

Tags: babeljs, ruby-on-rails-6, react-on-rails

I'm trying to set up on my app the gem 'react-rails', following https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails.

```
bundle install
rails webpacker:install
rails webpacker:install:react
```

He's set up the

```
app/javascript/components/ directory for your React components
 ReactRailsUJS setup in app/javascript/packs/application.js
 app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js for server-side rendering
```

but when I launch

```
rails generate react:install
```

it sends this warning

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 34494
       exist  app/javascript/components
   identical  app/javascript/components/.keep
warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".                                                                                           
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".                                                 
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".                                                          
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".                                              
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@7.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".                                                     
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".                                                   
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".                                             
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".                               
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".                                                                                        
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".                                                                             
File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  app/javascript/packs/application.js
   identical  app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js
```

And my localhost rendering doesn't work, and sends me :

```
undefined method `react_component' for #<#<Class:0x00007f9270ab7e80>:0x00007f9270ecd448>
```

Has anyone some hint ?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved part of it : I managed by quitting and coming back to my Terminal.
But now it can't read the react_component properly :

```
27:        <h1><%= react_component ("Coucou", { greeting: "Pipi" }) %></h1>
```

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'
```